# How to display short permalinks in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I can't find any solution to display permalinks like this http://domain.com/Ll8RG for my website posts and pages.

There are lots of plugins which can generate such short links to use in page text or inside php  template. But can't find nothing for permalinks.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: This is already built in, in the form of [default "ugly" permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Default:_.22Ugly.22). This are still available to you, and work even if you use "pretty" permalinks.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately client don't want to use such type /?p=N permalink. He want to use /9qF0F(5 symbols - letters and digits) permalinks.